# How to view the hadoop data directory structure?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have partitioned table in hive. So I wanna see the directory structure in hadoop hdfs?

From [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.0/hdfs_shell.html#ls), I have found the following command

```
hadoop fs -ls /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/
```

and `/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/` is my data path. But this command return

> ls: Cannot access /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/: No such file or
>   directory.

Am I missing something there?

Comment: Are you sure you have data in this path? How did you verify it? This error probably means you have nothing there or something is misconfigured.

Comment: My hadoop temp directory path is `/app/hadoop/tmp`, so the data path appended as `dfs/data/` to the temp directory. And `/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/` has sub directories like `current`, `detach/`, `tmp/` `blocksBeingWritten/` with two other files `in_use.lock`, `storage`.

Comment: Are these directories in HDFS or on your local disk? How did you create your Hive table?

Comment: I just went there with normal command line, and I just create hive table with normal sql with partition.

Comment: Have you tried doing `hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse` to see if your table is there?

Comment: Yea, those table are there under the above directory. Is this the default hdfs data directory?

Comment: I added that as an answer to give you more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, it seems you are looking for a temporary directory that you probably defined in the property `hadoop.tmp.dir`. This is a local directory, but when you do `hadoop fs -ls` you are looking at what files are available in HDFS, so you won't see anything.

Since you're looking or the Hive directories, you are looking for the following property in your hive-site.xml:

```
hive.metastore.warehouse.dir
```

The default is `/user/hive/warehouse`, so if you  haven't changed this property you should be able to do:

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse
```

And this should show you your table directories.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` was set in `hive-default.xml.template` file. I can see my table, table partitions under `/user/hive/warehouse` directory.

Answer (score 0):

check whether tmp directory is correctly set in your core-site.xml file and hdfs-site.xml. 
if not set, then the temporary directory of operating system(tmp in ubuntu and %temp% in windows) will be set to hadoop tmp folder, due to which you may lose your data after restarting your computer. Set this dfs.tmp.dir in both the xml and restart your cluster. It will work fine then.
even after this if it is not resolved, please give more details about partitioning table code and the table data too.